# how to read numbers from text

Tags: r

```
input                                                output
 car number and model     400708   

                              how to read just numeric form
```

input                                                output
     car number and model     400708

```
                              how to read just numeric form     from the above data
```

input                                                output
     car number and model     400708

```
                              how to read just numeric form     from the above data
```

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. please consider coming up with a function yourself first. Stackoverflow is not ment to solve your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract

```
df1$output <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\s+", "", df1$input))
```

---

Or if this is based on position, use substring

```
substring(df1$input, nchar(df1$input)-5)
```

Comment: thanks akrun for explaination of the codes you used , helped me a lot .

Comment: sorry for the error ..just low bandwidht made me click twice

Comment: could you help me with these i have been struggling since last 4 days to get the right solution 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/46359191/8626662

Answer (score 0):

A way you could use to automate this if you wanted to be sure that you were always extracting that 6-digit code is to use regular expressions to do so.

```
require(stringr)
input <- "S/O kk kumar sharma ropar rajasthan India 400708"
x<- str_extract(input, "\\d{6}$")
```

`""` tells regex that you are acting on a character string 
`\\d` says take just digits
`[6}` says take ONLY AND EXACTLY six digits
`$` says take them from the back of the string

This is the most effective way to operationalize if your addresses always come in in this fashion.

Comment: THanks a lot i was struggling with regular expressions since very long thanks for clearing the concept as well