# how to identify locations from text

Tags: r, api, for-loop, while-loop, geocoding

Here is sample to my function that getscodes

```
df= read.csv("secondary.csv",header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
S <- "s / O sk hungu 101 / 90 MODEL HOUSE TALAB GAGNI SHUKUL LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH 226001"
```

I recommend making all possible N-x strings where N is length of your string and x is variable length

```
allchr <- unlist(strsplit(S, ""))
listsubstr <- sapply(1:length(allchr), function(I) paste0(allchr[I:length(allchr)], collapse=""))

  # [1] "s / O sk hungu 101 / 90 MODEL HOUSE TALAB GAGNI SHUKUL LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH 226001"
  # [2] " / O sk hungu 101 / 90 MODEL HOUSE TALAB GAGNI SHUKUL LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH 226001" 
  # [3] "/ O sk hungu 101 / 90 MODEL HOUSE TALAB GAGNI SHUKUL LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH 226001"  
  # [4] " O sk hungu 101 / 90 MODEL HOUSE TALAB GAGNI SHUKUL LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH LUCKNOW UTTAR PRADESH 226001"
```

You can iterate through this list to check for valid geocodes. I have to provide pseudocode since I'm not sure how to check if a string is a valid geocode.

```
sapply(listsubstr, function(I) is.geocode(I))     # contains pseudocode
```

You could also do this with recursion though.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
             if (x is gecode) { # contains pseudocode
                   return(x)
             } else {
                   myfun(substr(x, 2, nchar(S)))
             }
         }
```

Comment: what is myfun over here and how do i apply this to whole column in the dataset i am trying something like 
 allchr <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(secondary$permanent_address, ""))) and i already have a loop df=with(secondary,laply(permanent_address, function(val){geoCode(val)})) that gives me geo coding  how can i fix a loop inside a loop to get geo loacations of all the addresses in the column

Comment: Edit your original post with your data format and more constraints on the solution you desire.

Comment: could you please take a look at my edited question and guide me i would be really thankful to you